# glGetString(GL_VENDOR) on hybrid graphics machines

Tags: opengl

glGetString(GL_VENDOR) returns "Intel" on PC laptops with an NVIDIA or AMD card and Intel graphics. Is there any way to programmatically get the vendor string of the higher end card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not just a problem of the vendor string, but of the graphics driver in general. Since the graphics driver actually implements the OpenGL API, it seems you are working with the Intel GPU by default. Try to change some setting of the operating system, so that you actually work with the nVidia/AMD card, then the vendor string should also return the respective value, of course.

Comment: This is the same conclusion I've come to myself. It has essentially boiled down to querying the OS for available graphics cards, iterating through them and trying to set the active graphics card, because you do end up dealing with the Intel card by default.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, 'is there a fixed or mandated format string describing the hardware?' - no. However, you will (typically) get more information using `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)`.

Comment: Tried that. It just returns "Intel HD graphics". The problem is that I have some shaders that crash when linking using Intel graphics, but work fine on AMD or NVIDIA graphics. So I'm trying to figure out a way to disable the unsupported shaders on Intel.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem this evening. Maybe this solution is the way, I've changed settings on nVidia Control Panel -> 3D Settings -> Use nVidia Processor (something like that, sorry I have polish version of the system). Regards.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround that I have had to use. The problem though  is that a user really should not have to care about this kind of stuff - the application should take care of it, which is the reasoning behind my question :)